# I implement SIPO shift register by using verilog, but unknown error comes out

Tags: verilog

Main file

```
module D_ff (q, D, Clk, Reset);
    input Clk, D, Reset;
    output q;
    always @ (posedge Clk);
        and(q, D, Reset);
endmodule

module SIPO(Clk, Reset, Data, Out1, Out2, Out3, Out4);
    input Clk, Reset, Data;
    output Out1, Out2, Out3, Out4;
    begin
    D_ff sr0 (Out0, Data, Clk, Reset);
    D_ff sr1 (Out1, Out0, Clk, Reset);
    D_ff sr2 (Out2, Out1, Clk, Reset);
    D_ff sr3 (Out3, Out2, Clk, Reset);
    end
endmodule
```

Testbench file

```
 'timescale 1ps/1ps

    module tb_SIPO;
        reg Clk, Reset, Data;
        wire Out1, Out2, Out3, Out4;

        SIPO(Clk, Reset, Data, Out1, Out2, Out3, Out4);

        initial
        Clk=0;  
        always #11 Clk=~Clk;
        Reset=1; Data=0;
        initial begin
            #15 Reset=1; Data=1;
            #20 Reset=1; Data=0;
            #30 Reset=1; Data=0;
            #10 Reset=0; Data=1;
            #20 Reset=0; Data=0;
            #5 Reset=0; Data=0;
            #20 Reset=0; Data=0;
            #20 Reset=0; Data=0;
            #20 Reset=0; Data=0;
            #20 Reset=0; Data=0;
            #70 Reset=0; Data=0;
            #5 $finish;
        end

    endmodule
```

> Error: (vlog-13053) C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/tb_sipo.v(1): near >"'t": Illegal base specifier in numeric constant.
>
> ** Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/tb_sipo.v(1): near >"'t": syntax error, unexpected BASE, expecting class.

I don't know what the error means. there is no 't' in my program and I can't see any illegal base specifier.
What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've used `timescale` for specifying the reference time unit for the simulator. But it should be:

```
`timescale
```

and not:

```
'timescale
```

`'` is used to specify numbers in Verilog, e.g. `8'hFF`. That's why compiler is looking for a numeric constant.

Comment: Thank you very much! You save my life. But When I compile it and simulate the file, 'Error loading design' error came out. what is this error?

Comment: IMHO `D_ff` module should not compile because of couple errors and your error might address this problem.